# How to migrate ASP.NET membership to SAML in an MVC application?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, saml

I want to migrate the ASP.NET membership authentication/authorization of an MVC application into SAML.

Could you please provide any suggestions or links that can guide me on implementation.

I know we can use Azure App Proxy and SAML SSO for on-premise applications.

But On-premise MVC application has ASP.NET Membership implemented for Role authorization and LDAP for authentication.

How can we convert it to enable SAML. Do we need any code change.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: The authentication will be performed by the IdP so you don't need that in your application. The roles will come from the IdP as SAML Attributes. Ask the IdP admin to release the required attributes that allow your application make authorisation decisions. You could convert SAML Attributes to application Roles and re-use your existing Role authorisation code but you won't need authentication code as the IdP does that in SAML.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET membership does everything inside the application using a database.

So authentication and authorisation are both handled by the membership provider.

In SAML, this is outsourced to the SAML provider.

On login, the application redirects to the IDP where the user authenticates and then a SAML token is returned that contains the SAML assertions i.e. claims some of which may be roles.

So you may have to migrate the users to the SAML IDP. If they are already there, use the NameID claim in the assertion to match against the user in the database.

To talk to the SAML IDP, you need to add a SAML [client side stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Comment: Azure proxy and SAML SSO will generate SAML 2.0 token right. Is this not the right approach?

Comment: Yes but ypur application still needs the plumbing to handle SAML.

Comment: I prefer just going direct to Azure.

Comment: Could you please look into below query aswell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63895561/how-to-get-claims-from-azure-saml-sso-token